# Making flat reflective surfaces look realistic

Tags: materials

If I create a simple shiny metal material, by using Principle BSDF, crank up Metallic to 1.0, and drop the Roughness down, then apply it to a sphere and a cube. I get this:
[image: glossy metal material applied to sphere and cube, with smooth shading]

The sphere looks good, but the cube does not. I think I understand what's happening: the sphere has a convex surface, so it reflecting the whole environment texture, but the cube is flat and therefore only reflects a small portion of it. But the small portion looks blurry.

How do I get a realistic-looking shiny cube? Do I need infinite resolution in the environment texture? Does the environment need bringing closer? Have I got the wrong idea completely?

Edit: as per someone's suggestion, I switched to Render Preview, added a world environment texture, and I also switched to Cycles rendering. The image below is the result - still a blurry and unsatisfactory cube!
[image]

Comment: please pack your image and share your file

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to this forum, and I don't quite understand your comment. Do you mean share the .blend file? How can I do this? Thank you!

Comment: To pack the image, go into File > External Data >Pack Resources, and to share your file use a platform like workupload. It's weird that your HDRI seems blurry if the Roughness value of your material is at 0...

Comment: https://workupload.com/file/2Nu7g7LCjZc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the *Roughness* of your *Principled BSDF* at 0 and the glossiness will be maximal and sharp (the sharpness will also depends on the HDRI resolution by the way):

[image]

Comment: Amazing, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You are viewing your objects through "Material Preview" mode (aka LookDev) - this mode uses a hidden (blurred out) HDRI for the lightings and reflections. You can either extend the viewport shading options (top right of the viewport next to the 4 "circles" - click the little arrow) "and unblur" the world (second image), or use Render Preview mode, which requires you to provide your own HDRI in the World Shader (good free ones can be found here - https://polyhaven.com/hdris).

[image: Shade1]

[image: Shade2]

Notice the "blurry reflections" are simply a good reflection of a blurry HDRI.

Comment: Thank you, Christopher. I have edited my question with the results of your suggestion. I still don't think the cube looks right!